# Remove padding/space in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, padding

can someone tell me how to remove the space between the gray rectangle and the frame of the node, such that the text of the node flushes with the main text?

[image: Example Image]

Here is my minimal example using LuaLatex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm ,right=1.5cm ,top=2.25cm,footskip=1cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\tikzset{every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw,line width=1sp}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray}, show background rectangle]
\node[] (name) at (0,0) {Hello, World};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could adjust `inner frame sep`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm ,right=1.5cm ,top=2.25cm,footskip=1cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\tikzset{every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw,line width=1sp}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray}, show background rectangle,inner frame sep=0pt]
\node[] (name) at (0,0) {Hello, World};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it seems I have to apologize for not diving deep enough into the documentation.
Thank you very much, works perfectly!

Comment: @Philipp You didn't learn all 1321 pages of the documentation by heart? :P No need to apologise :)

Comment: There is also the `tight background` option, that does the same thing.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Oh, good to know! You should write an answer!

Comment: No need for an extra answer - it is the same method just an alternative option that does the same thing.